# prng,python, tkinter,need to change picture

Tags: python, tkinter, random, messagebox

I ran into this problem and don't know how to solve it.
When I press the "generate" button(`self.gen`), my picture 11 changes to picture 22.
BUT I need the image 11 to NOT change when the button is clicked and an error occurs(`messagebox.showerror` pops up)  OR  so that after closing the `messagebox.showerror`, picture 22 changes to 11

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *  
from tkinter import messagebox, scrolledtext
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from random import randint

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.window.title("Генератор") 
        self.window['bg'] = '#FFF5EE'
        self.window.geometry('660x550') 
        self.window.resizable(False,False)

        self.lb1 = Label(self.window, text="Enter:", background='#FFF5EE', font = ("Comic Sans MS", 14))  
        self.lb1.grid(column=0, row=2) 

        self.lb2 = Label(self.window, text="min(1-999)",background='#FFF5EE', font = ("Comic Sans MS", 12))  
        self.lb2.grid(column=1, row=3) 

        self.lb3 = Label(self.window, text="max(1-999)", background='#FFF5EE', font = ("Comic Sans MS", 12))  
        self.lb3.grid(column=1, row=4) 

        self.lb4 = Label(self.window, text="amount of numbers", background='#FFF5EE', font = ("Comic Sans MS", 12))  
        self.lb4.grid(column=4, row=3)  

        self.txt2 = Entry(self.window,width=10, borderwidth=3)  
        self.txt2.grid(column=2, row=3)  

        self.txt3 = Entry(self.window,width=10, borderwidth=3)  
        self.txt3.grid(column=2, row=4) 

        self.txt4 = Entry(self.window,width=10, borderwidth=3)  
        self.txt4.grid(column=5, row=3)  

        self.scrolltxt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.window, width=30, height=3, borderwidth=7, state='disabled')
        self.scrolltxt.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.image = Image.open("C:\\Users\\ПК\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\лб1\\11.png")
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.gen = Button(self.window, width = 15, text="Generate", command = lambda:[self.clicked1(), self.gen1()])
        self.gen.grid(row=4, column=6)

        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.window, height=230, width=230)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=4)
        self.image = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image = self.photo)


        self.btn = Button(self.window, width = 15, text="Delete", command=lambda:[self.delete(),self.clicked2()])  
        self.btn.grid(column=6, row=5)

        self.exit = Button(self.window, width = 15, text="Exit", command=lambda: [self.clicked3(), quit()])
        self.exit.grid(column=6, row=6)

        self.i = Button(self.window, width = 8,text = "i", font = ("Eras Bold ITC", 10) , command = self.inf)
        self.i.grid(row = 0,column = 6)
 
        self.window.mainloop()


    def clicked1(self):
        print("clicked1")
        self.image = Image.open("C:\\Users\\ПК\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\лб1\\22.png")  
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=4)
        self.image = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw',image=self.photo)

    def gen1(self):
        try:
                MinNum = int(self.txt2.get())
                MaxNum = int(self.txt3.get())
                Num = int(self.txt4.get())
        except ValueError:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Якщо не рвешся у висоту, шишок не наб'єш.")
        else:
                Nums = " "
                if MinNum <= MaxNum:
                        i = 0
                        while i < Num:
                                numOne = randint(MinNum, MaxNum)
                                Nums = Nums + ' ' + str(numOne)
                                i += 1
                        self.scrolltxt.config(state="normal") # enable the text box 
                        self.scrolltxt.delete(1.0, END)
                        self.scrolltxt.insert(INSERT, str(Nums) + "\n") 
                        self.scrolltxt.config(state="disabled") # disable the text box
                else:
                        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Якщо не рвешся у висоту, шишок не наб'єш.")
        

    def delete(self):
        self.txt4.delete(0, END)
        self.txt3.delete(0, END)
        self.txt2.delete(0, END)
        self.scrolltxt.config(state="normal") # enable the text box 
        self.scrolltxt.delete(1.0, END)
        self.scrolltxt.config(state="disabled") # disable the text box

    def clicked2(self):
        print("clicked2")
        self.image = Image.open("C:\\Users\\ПК\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\лб1\\11.png")  
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=4)
        self.image = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw',image=self.photo)

    def clicked3(self):
        messagebox.showinfo("Це Звірополіс. Будь-хто може бути будь-ким.", "Хто сказав, що неможливе недосяжне?! Пошкодуйте цього дивака.")

    def inf(self):
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "Лисичка замахалась")
    
app = App()
```

is it possible to implement this through tkinter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `command` argument of `self.gen` to:

```
self.gen = Button(self.window, width = 15, text="Generate", command=self.gen1)
```

And move the call to  `clicked1()` into the `if` block of `gen1()` so it will only be called when conditions are accepted

```
def gen1(self):
    try:
        MinNum = int(self.txt2.get())
        MaxNum = int(self.txt3.get())
        Num = int(self.txt4.get())
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showerror(
            "Error",
            "Якщо не рвешся у висоту, шишок не наб'єш."
        )
    else:
        Nums = " "
        if MinNum <= MaxNum:
            i = 0
            while i < Num:
                numOne = randint(MinNum, MaxNum)
                Nums = Nums + ' ' + str(numOne)
                i += 1
            self.scrolltxt.config(state="normal") # enable the text box 
            self.scrolltxt.delete(1.0, END)
            self.scrolltxt.insert(INSERT, str(Nums) + "\n") 
            self.scrolltxt.config(state="disabled") # disable the text box
            self.clicked1()  # call the 'clicked1' method
        else:
            messagebox.showerror(
                "Error", 
                "Якщо не рвешся у висоту, шишок не наб'єш."
            )
```